# How can you copy and edit value of 'textarea' and post to another 'textarea' via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an example textarea markup as follows

```
<textarea>
  <module name="TOP_FA" COUNT="5" ></module>
  <module name="TOP_FA" COUNT="5" POSITION="QB" ></module>
  <module name="TOP_FA" COUNT="5" POSITION="RB" ></module>
  <module name="TOP_FA" COUNT="5" POSITION="WR" ></module>
  <module name="TOP_FA" COUNT="5" POSITION="TE" ></module>
  <module name="TOP_FA" COUNT="5" POSITION="PK" ></module>
  <module name="TOP_FA" COUNT="5" POSITION="Def" ></module>
</textarea>
```

I am trying to ajax that page with the textarea , then add an attr to each module and post in on another page. I assumed it to be easy and thought this would work. Any ideas ? When i post ajax back the url paremeter is not being added.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/csetup?L=43570&C=HMPGMSG&SEQNO=34',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
        var tmpElement = $('<div>' + $(data).find('textarea').val() + '</div>');
        $(tmpElement).each(function (index) {
            $(this).find("module").attr('YEAR', '2021')
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: baseURLDynamic + "/" + year + "/message?LEAGUE_ID=" + league_id + "&NAME=message34",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            data: tmpElement,
            beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                console.log(settings.url);
            },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("SUCCESS");
            },
            error: function (xhr) {}
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr) {}
});
```

Comment: The first URL, https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/csetup?L=43570&C=HMPGMSG&SEQNO=34, does not contain any `<textarea>` tags. Also, it's extremely weird to have a `<module>` tag inside a `<textarea>` tag. Are you sure that's right? And what exactly is a `<module>` tag anyway?

Comment: Unless your logged in you can’t see it

Comment: Your example doesn't show any `<module>` elements with `YEAR="2021"` attributes. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73642488/edit) to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.